# Given P(A|B) and P(B|C), can I compute P(A|B,C) without assumptions of conditional independence?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If no (which I suspect to be the case) would assuming $P(A|C)=P(A)$ be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

No, any expansion of $P(A|B,C)$ will need three-term probabilities and what you already know is just two-term probabilities and pairwise relations. Even if you know every probability pairwise, you'd still need a three-term probability or an assumption over the triple, which means the assumption $P(A|C)=P(A)$ would not be enough as well.